# Add loopback as well as letter input

Tags: java

I am new to Java and and learning to the best of my ability. I am working on an assignment that takes an exam score and converts it into a letter grade. I have no problem writing the code for that, in fact, it works well as is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class grades {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte Score;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Start program
        System.out.println("Welcome to the automated grading system!");
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your exam score from 0-100. Press 'E' to Exit");
        }   
        Score = input.nextByte();
        {
        if(Score >= 90 && Score <= 100) {
            System.out.println("Your Grade is an A.");
        } else if (Score >= 80 && Score <= 89) {
            System.out.println("your Grade is a B.");
        } else if (Score >= 70 && Score <= 79) { 
            System.out.println("Your Grade is a C.");
        } else if (Score >= 60 && Score <= 69){
                {System.out.println("Your Grade is a D.");}         
        }else if (Score < 50){{
            System.out.println("Your Grade is a F.");}
        }}
    }
}
```

The problem I am having a hard time with is with the users's input of a character 'E' instead of a number. How do I add that in addition to what I have? Also, I am trying to make the program loop back and start over once I enter a number, but the first message is just repeated over and over and over.
So I need to know how to make that happen.
I know I have to establish a boolean, but I'm not sure where to put the while statement.

Comment: Why are there so many unnecessary blocks?

Comment: Instead of using `input.nextByte()` (which will fail on input that you're not expecting like 10101 for example) use `.next()` and read it as a string - then check if the string is "E" and if not, try to parse it as a number and issue an error printout if it's not a number or if it is a number but it's out of range.

Comment: Sorry Andrew Li, I am new to all of this and I am doing my best to understand it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I am having a hard time with is with the users's input of a character 'E' instead of a number.

You can read a string instead of a byte. Convert the string to an integer when you actually need it.

> Also, I am trying to make the program loop back and start over once I enter a number

Try a while-true and break when needed.

> I know I have to establish a boolean but not sure where to put the while statement at

Around everything you want to repeat.

For example

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your exam score from 0-100. Press 'E' to Exit");
    input = sc.next();
    if (input.equals("E")) break; // exit loop

    int score = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // check score

}
```

Comment: I'd actually prefer a regular while-loop that doesn't check twice per iteration if `input.equals("E")` or alternatively modify the condition in do-while to be `while(true)`

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to do it the way I had, but you make a good point

Comment: Thank you for the input, I was able to get it working and the program terminates when 'E' or 'e' is entered. Just trying to figure out if there is a statement I can put on the code after 'e' is entered but before the termination. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can create a block statement for  the if statement around the break and do whatever you want.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks so much for the help. I was really stumbling on this for a few days now. I'm such a newB.

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` will read the next character that is entered, from there you can convert to the type that you need if you want to switch between char and int. If you want the program to loopback you can initialize the "choice" variable outside of the loop, and do a `do while` loop where the condition is that choice equals whatever input you want to use for the loopback.